# Why am I getting this error while deploying spring boot project into jboss while it runs perfectly in embedded tomcat server?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, gradle, jboss, war

```
11:29:28,695 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.10.Final}
11:29:28,698 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
11:29:28,737 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
11:29:28,844 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
11:29:29,195 WARN  [ae.cbd.clo.JBossWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
11:29:29,208 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
11:29:29,213 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Application startup failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(JBossContextConfig.java:187) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:115) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3775) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindManyToOne(AnnotationBinder.java:2958) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindOneToOne(AnnotationBinder.java:3153) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1823) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:925) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:752) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:249) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:222) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:265) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885) [hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) [spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) [spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) [spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) [spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 29 more

11:29:29,298 ERROR [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) JBAS018206: Webapp [/CLOService] is unavailable due to startup errors
11:29:29,299 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) JBWEB001103: Error detected during context /CLOService start, will stop it
11:29:29,317 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./CLOService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./CLOService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:168)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96)
    ... 6 more

11:29:29,324 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (HttpManagementService-threads - 1) JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([{"deployment" => "CLOService.war"}]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./CLOService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./CLOService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}
11:29:29,325 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "CLOService.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./CLOService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./CLOService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}
11:29:30,315 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment CLOService.war (runtime-name: CLOService.war) in 988ms
11:29:30,317 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (HttpManagementService-threads - 1) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."CLOService.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./CLOService.realm (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."CLOService.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./CLOService
      service jboss.web.connector.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.connector.http: JBAS018007: Error starting web connector
```

I am trying to deploy a spring boot war into jboss server. It runs perfectly in the embedded Tomcat server but it throws this error when deploying to Jboss. i am using hibernate v5.2.10 and hibernate jpa v2.1.

Comment: Have you actually read the stack trace?

Comment: I have. The java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey says that foriegn key method is not found. I have updated all the hibernate and jpa jars to the latest version still same issue. this Runs with tomcat but not with jboss. why?

Comment: No you have seen the error you haven't read it, or used google (which will point you to several answers on stack overflow).

Comment: I have looked around for answers which all told me to update the jars. I did as said still no progress.

Comment: Search again. The issue is your server has old JPA jars which take precedence over your application JPA jars. Set class loading to parent last (or whatever that is nowadays in jBoss).

Comment: Thanks you . I solved the problem. Problem was the server jars were outdated though I could not implement class loading I directly replaced the static jars in  the server with latest versions.

Comment: Hello @SumanRuleBreakerShaw I am having the same issue. where do i update the server jars??